# Initialize character array

Tags: java, arrays

I am just new to Java and I am struck in my program with Array initialization because it's not working and contains some garbage. This is what I am doing:

```
char[] expArray = new char[expEv.length];   //expEv.length is int - expEv is another array
//I have tried all following but not working

expArray = {'\0'};     // error i get: Array constants can only be used in initializers
expArray = {'',};
expArray = {'\0'};

System.out.println("array value: " + expArray); // prints " array value: [C@1cd761a "
```

**Edit:** I have also tried to use `char[] expArray = new char[expEv.length] {'\0'};` but this doesn't work as

Please help me with this and explain the array initialization for the context.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion that these people are giving you is incorrect since I bet you still want to create a variable sized array. In fact, what you are currently doing is 100% fine.

Java automatically initializes variables that are not explicitly set. In your case, each value of your array is initialized to the null character. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is what each variable type will be initialized to.

The only reason you are getting gibberish when printing like that is because Java's built in `toString()` is not doing what you're expecting. Here is what the built-in `toString()` is actually returning:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

If you really want to print the array's values then you need to do something like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(expArray ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but Java just doesn't allow you to do that. However, this may be close enough:

```
char[] expArray = {'\0'};
expArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(expArray, expEv.length);
```

Though, in the case of initializing the array with a `'\0'`, that is completely unnecessary, since the array creation itself will clear all the elements to zero.